# Which xml attribute is to be set to disable android seekbar

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android, seekbar

Please help me to disable the seekbar through the xml file rather than through the code

```
<SeekBar
    ........
    android:clickable="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Have tried with all the above attributes, but cant disable the seekbar.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. And as far as I know android:enabled is used for TextView only

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` works. But, android:enabled="false" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27779040/3819411) said you can override `setOnTouchListener` event on `SeekBar` object and return `true` for not allowing user to change control value.
I hope this helps ;)