# Disable changes on seekbar by client

Tags: android, custom-controls, seekbar

I have a SeekBar that will change the progress when I require it to, but I don't want the user to be able to change it manually.

I tried to set the SeekBar as this:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:progress="10"
        android:max="100"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:thumb="@drawable/transparent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/customprogressbar" />
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

---

That's more or less an example of how this is going to be seen by the client.

I used a custom style because in the future I'll need to change the background images and the progress depending on which section the SeekBar will be.

Thanks for all!

[image: No given description by asker]

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136569/how-to-set-an-android-seekbar-to-be-unmoveable-frozen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set an Android SeekBar to be unmoveable/frozen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136569/how-to-set-an-android-seekbar-to-be-unmoveable-frozen)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One thing you can do is to disable 
the seekbar,
Like `seekbar.setEnabled(false)`

doing so framework will not accept any
Touch event from user and you
Can change progress level only through code.

I hope this will help you.......

Comment: Though you might want to include a custom drawable as setting the seekbar to disabled will change the look of the seekbar.

Comment: @Arjun, I have tested what you sugest me, and it works ;) Thanks!

Comment: I want the seekbar to be movable only by thumb and disable the click. how to do it ?

Answer (score 72):

You can use **android:enabled="false"** , but it will display **disable effect** [darken your seekbar].

So if you want to display enable seekbar with no response to thumb activity, implement touch event handler with return true as shown below.

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
 }
});
```

Comment: How would I return the default `onTouch` behaviours? Say if I need to enable and disable touch according to a type.

Comment: kotlin answer : seekBar1.setOnTouchListener { _: View?, _: MotionEvent? -> true }

Answer (score 2):

Just return false from onTouch method of CustomSeekBar class.

Hope this works !

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to display enable seekbar with no response to thumb activity, implement touch event handler with return true as shown below.

```
  seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
  {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
     {
        return true;
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to disable the seekbar, Like  kotlin

val pro = popupContent.findViewById(R.id.penoptionsizeslider)

//now disable it here

pro.setEnabled(false)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **seekbar.isEnabled = false** to disable seekbar. It worked for me