# Disable seekbar inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I need to play the audio inside `RecyclerView` . Requirement is `SeekBar` will be enable after user clicked the play button . So i tried.

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seek_Media_Player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But its not working . `android:clickable="false"` worked when i use `SeekBar` inside an `Activity` or `Fragment` but not inside `RecyclerView`. I also tried to set those attribute at runtime but not worked.

Setting `setEnabled(false)` making `SeekBar` invisible. I have been busting my head on this from last 6 hours. I am posting the item image just to show . Please let me know how can i disable/enable click on `SeekBar`.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284219/disable-changes-on-seekbar-by-client

Comment: this is a hack you can set touch listener and return true I nside onTouch method.. there will. e better solution than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found the solution . It was suspected previously but i was looking for some other way to do it . I thought problem was somewhere in my code . but it was't. Below is the complete solution i have used.

```
public class CustomSeekBar extends AppCompatSeekBar {
private boolean fuzzyEnable;

public void setFuzzyEnable(boolean fuzzyEnable) {
    this.fuzzyEnable = fuzzyEnable;
}
public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return fuzzyEnable?super.onTouchEvent(event):true;
}

}
```